# Xcode freezes when trying to open or compile .xib files

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I'm using Mountain Lion with Xcode 4.1.
When I open an XIB or compile an XIB, Xcode doesn't respond.
What am I doing wrong?

I had a problem with compiling when I had Xcode 4.4 for Mountain Lion too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need provide mode detail about the problem. You may change Deployment Target of the .xib files on interface builder. Select your .xib files and change assign latest version of deployment target.

[image: interface builder]